# In the nextjs project environment variable in k8s is undefined

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, dockerfile, environment-variables

The project has api endpoints that have values ​​if they are in a dev environment or docker containers (work normally / have value).
However, in a prod/qa environment in k8s it has no value, even though the env is in the POD.

prod/qa:

[image]

local dev/docker:

[image]

The two ways I'm trying to call. Both are api endpoints:

```
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache'

export default async function ClientDataBase(): Promise<ClientProps> {
  noStore()
  const API_CLIENT = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BFF_ORM_CLIENT
  if (!API_CLIENT) {
    console.log("API_CLIENT not found")
  }
...
}
```

```
async function fetchData() {
  const apiTest = process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_BFF_ORM_STATUS']
  if (!apiTest) {
    console.log("API TESTE SEM VALOR")
  }
...
}
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts as dependencies
WORKDIR /front
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
FROM node:lts as builder
WORKDIR /front
COPY . .
COPY --from=dependencies /front/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build
FROM node:lts as runner
WORKDIR /front
ENV YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/dev/shm/yarn_cache
ENV NODE_ENV production
# If you are using a custom next.config.js file, uncomment this line.
# COPY --from=builder /my-project/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /front/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /front/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /front/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /front/package.json ./package.json
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

And once again the form I'm calling works in local dev and local docker.

STACK:

- NEXTJS: 14.X
- YARN
- TYPESCRIPT: 5.3.3
- DOCKERFILE

**EDIT:**
I am defining the environment variables in the same way as shown in the official nextjs documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

The environment variables in the development environment are defined in .env.local, in qa/prod they are defined through the k8s envconfigmap which is in the code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: [SAME PROJECT NAME WITHOUT THE BRACKETS]
data: 
  NEXT_PUBLIC_BFF_ORM_CLIENT: "HELLO, WORD!"
  NEXT_PUBLIC_BFF_ORM_STATUS: "HELLO, WORD!"
```

Comment: please show kubernetes manifests

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't send it, I don't have access to this layer. Can you say what might be going on?

Comment: Nothing you've shown in the question sets any `NEXT_PUBLIC_...` environment variable at all.  Can you [edit] the question to show where that gets set, and how it's different between the two environments?

Comment: @David Maze. II'm going to edit my question, but I'll say that there's no difference between what is defined in dev/qa/prod other than the values ​​of environment variables

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the configuration of the ConfigMap is correct. The issue might arise from incorrect injection of the ConfigMap into the pod or deployment.